# Android Studio Emulator in Mac is not connected to internet

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am using Android studio 3.1.2. I am using Nexus emulator. I am facing it is not getting connected to internet. Any idea how to make it work. I am new to Mac.

I have tried creating new one also. connected, No Internet is the result

[image]

Comment: Maybe try to recreate newly created Android emulator or select 'Wipe Data' for the emulator and then 'Cold Boot Now' - form Android Virtual Device Manager, which is part of Android Studio IDE. I hope this helps you.

Comment: Tried creating new only that is also shows the same result.:-(